# How can I prolong my life?

Tags: dnd-5e

I'm not going to lie to you. I want to become immortal. Yes, I'm fine with watching all my friends and relatives dying, never liked them much anyway. In fact, outliving a few of my obnoxious friends is exactly what I need... Oh, I would love to watch them shrink and wrinkle while I'm forever young.

So I've been doing some research. It turns out that very powerful druids have a [timeless body](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/druid#ClassFeatures) that allows them to age really slowly. That sounds cool but I'm not into druids. Too naturalistic, too neutral, too... dirty? Anyway, definitely not for me.

Then, there's the option of becoming a Lich. Well, I have to admit, that's a bit extreme even for me -- and that says a lot. That said, it's not out of the question... But I'd like to explore my options first.

Finally, I learned about a [powerful spell](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/clone) that produces an exact copy of myself that stands inert until I die. When that happens, my soul transfers to this body and ta-da, I'm alive again. I have to admit, that this is by far the best option I know of so far (with the worst one being a druid). That said, the transfer of soul part sounds a bit scary.

So now I'm asking you, my dear shady, hooded person whom I just met in this awful tavern in the most infamous part of the city: How can I prolong my life? Remember that I'm not looking to become invincible (I wouldn't oppose it of course), just prolonging my life for as long as possible. Ideally, I would like to avoid complicated procedures such as transfering souls and the such (too much work) but for lack of better options I would do anything. Money and ethics, of course, are not a problem (never have been).

I've opened my notebook and I'm all ears. It goes without saying that if your solution is acceptable I will make you rich. Wench! Another drink for this person whom I cannot see the face of!

Comment: I love your wording here but I believe this may be a duplicate. Does this answer your question? [What magic extends life or grants immortality?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/153906/what-magic-extends-life-or-grants-immortality)

Comment: In that question I have an answer that goes over pretty much every way I could find to make someone either immortal or at the very least prolong their life.

Comment: Snap! For a hooded, shady figure in an awful tavern in the most infamous part of the city you're quite the fella. You could have gotten my money and run away. This does answer my question. Thank you very much faceless person.